# pip install glove-python-binary not working asdas

Tags: python

I encountered an error when I am trying to run the code for the GloVe package in Python3. I'm currently using Windows 10 with Anaconda3. And I'm looking for assistance with this issue.

Here's the code I tried. pip install glove-python-binary

And here's the error message I got. ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement glove-python-binary (from versions: none) ERROR: No matching distribution found for glove-python-binary

Comment: What version of python are you running on?

Comment: Error means that anaconda's repository does not have version available for your combination of windows and python version..